# fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm using avr-gcc and avrdude to program ATMEGA328 through RPi3. I want to use C++ instead of C, so I created a simple C++ file and tried to build it:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void delayms( uint16_t millis ) 
{
    while ( millis ) 
    {
        _delay_ms( 1 );
        millis--;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    DDRD = 0xFF;

    while( 1 )
    {
        PORTD = 0xFF;
        delayms( 1000 );
        PORTD = 0x00;
        delayms( 1000 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My Makefile:

```
CC=/usr/bin/avr-gcc
MEGA=328p
CFLAGS=-g -Os -Wall -mcall-prologues -mmcu=atmega$(MEGA)
OBJ2HEX=/usr/bin/avr-objcopy
PROG=/usr/local/bin/avrdude
SOURCE=$(SOURCE)
DEVICE=$(DEVICE)

program : $(SOURCE).hex
        $(PROG) -c linuxgpio -p m$(MEGA) -P $(DEVICE) -e -B 2.0 -U lfuse:w:0xe2:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m
        $(PROG) -c linuxgpio -p m$(MEGA) -P $(DEVICE) -U flash:w:$(SOURCE).hex

%.obj : %.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.hex : %.obj
        $(OBJ2HEX) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@

clean :
        rm -f *.hex *.obj *.o
```

I build it the following way:

```
sudo make DEVICE=atmega328p SOURCE=blink
```

The problem is, if I save the file as **blink.c**, it will build properly, but if I save it as **blink.cpp**, it calls the **g++** compiler, instead of **avr-g++**, so I updated the first line in the Makefile to this:

```
CC=/usr/bin/avr-g++
```

But still the same problem persists and I keep getting the following error:

```
g++    -c -o blink.o blink.cpp
blink.cpp:3:20: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory
 #include <avr/io.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'blink.o' failed
make: *** [blink.o] Error 1
```

If I run the following command manually, it builds just fine:

```
avr-g++    -c -o blink.o blink.cpp
```

I don't understand why it tries to run **g++** instead of **avr-g++** when I run the Makefile, even though I strictly specified **avr-g++**. Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: `%.obj : %.o` what is this? Are you creating .obj files from .o files by compiling them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> **Compiling C++ programs**
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a recipe of the form ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’.

Try setting the variable CXX instead of CC.